# problems with two different python environment messing up

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I am using jupyter notebook (by anaconda) and pycharm (community edition, **not with anaconda**).
it worked well till tried to install some packages (numpy, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn) with pycharm (settings/file interpreter/+...).
since then, when I try to import packages in jupyter notebook, i got the error

> [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

I tried to reinstall anaconda several times, and manually delete all the files related to those packages. then I uninstalled pycharm, and reinstalled anaconda.
now I can import and use pandas, numpy and matplotlib, but can't import others packages.
this code is an example of what happens when I try to import a seaborn package. it's the same with other packages.

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-a84c0541e888> in <module>
----> 1 import seaborn as sns

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\__init__.py in <module>
     1 # Import seaborn objects
----> 2 from .rcmod import *  # noqa: F401,F403
     3 from .utils import *  # noqa: F401,F403
     4 from .palettes import *  # noqa: F401,F403
     5 from .relational import *  # noqa: F401,F403

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\rcmod.py in <module>
     5 import matplotlib as mpl
     6 from cycler import cycler
----> 7 from . import palettes
     8 
     9 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\palettes.py in <module>
     7 from .external import husl
     8 
----> 9 from .utils import desaturate, get_color_cycle
    10 from .colors import xkcd_rgb, crayons
    11 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\utils.py in <module>
     8 
     9 import numpy as np
---> 10 from scipy import stats
    11 import pandas as pd
    12 import matplotlib as mpl

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py in <module>
   134 
   135     # Allow distributors to run custom init code
--> 136     from . import _distributor_init
   137 
   138     from scipy._lib import _pep440

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\scipy\_distributor_init.py in <module>
    59             os.chdir(libs_path)
    60             for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(libs_path, '*dll')):
---> 61                 WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
    62         finally:
    63             os.chdir(owd)

~\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
   379 
   380         if handle is None:
--> 381             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
   382         else:
   383             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

another example

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-b7c74cbf5af0> in <module>
----> 1 import sklearn

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py in <module>
     80     from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401
     81     from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
---> 82     from .base import clone
     83     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     84 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in <module>
     15 from . import __version__
     16 from ._config import get_config
---> 17 from .utils import _IS_32BIT
     18 from .utils._tags import (
     19     _DEFAULT_TAGS,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in <module>
     18 import warnings
     19 import numpy as np
---> 20 from scipy.sparse import issparse
     21 
     22 from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py in <module>
    134 
    135     # Allow distributors to run custom init code
--> 136     from . import _distributor_init
    137 
    138     from scipy._lib import _pep440

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\scipy\_distributor_init.py in <module>
     59             os.chdir(libs_path)
     60             for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(libs_path, '*dll')):
---> 61                 WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
     62         finally:
     63             os.chdir(owd)

~\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    379 
    380         if handle is None:
--> 381             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    382         else:
    383             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

solutions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what else can i provide? when i try to import packages, i get a similar code

Comment: Have you tried installing the missing packages using `conda install`?

Comment: What's the advantage of having 2 python installations, esp. when you are an unexperienced user? Jupyter Notebook doesn't require Anaconda. This is asking for trouble!